# How can I search the iPad only apps/games on iTunes?

Tags: itunes

I can browse the iPad apps/games but they are often also iPhone/iPod. How can I search only among the iPad apps/games and not iPhone/iPod apps/games?

Is there any filter os something in iTunes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Click the iTunes Store button in the top right corner of iTunes (11.0 and above)

  [image: Click the iTunes Store button]
- Click the App Store Button in the middle of the screen and then iPad.

[image: Click the App Store Button in the middle of the screen and then iPad.]

- Click the iPad list that appears on the right and then select what apps you would like to see that are exclusively on the iPad.

[image: Click and filter through the iPad list]

Note: Some iPad apps that you may see are also available on the iPhone, but that does not mean they are not also native iPad apps. When you click on a certain app, most of them display "This app is designed for both iPhone and iPad." (see below for pictures). If it does not say that, the app is **only for iPad, not iPhone** (For instance, the app Things for iPad).  Therefore, the apps that are shown here are native iPad apps.
[image: "This app is designed for both iPad and iPhone."]
[image: "Only iPad App"]

### Update:

While the solution and the steps above detail which apps are iPad only, this solution can take a long time and is not extremely efficient. Therefore, [this website](http://www.apps-aholic.com/ipad-only-deals.html) details iPad exclusive apps that are on sale. The contents of the website are updated several times throughout the day.

Comment: The problem is I get also iPhone apps, which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Those apps that you see are iPhone and iPad apps. They are iPad apps though. So you only want to see exclusive iPad only apps, not all iPad apps?

Comment: Exactly: if(iPad && !iPhone) ;D Or in a human language: The App has to be iPad compatible and iPhone/iPod incompatible.

Comment: I'm sorry, but may I ask why? For what purpose? Not the answer you requested, but [this website](http://www.apps-aholic.com/ipad-only-deals.html) shows exclusive iPad apps. However it shows only iPad exclusive apps that are on sale.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at the link you provided. Why I need exclusive iPad apps? I am making an App and I need to check some iPad only "apps" ;).

Comment: Please, add the link to your answer so I can select your answer as the best.

Comment: Good luck on your app!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "search" for iPad only apps (and not just browse certain categories for iPad only Apps):

1. Select iTunes Store in iTunes
2. Enter search term in search field (upper left corner)
3. Select "iPad Apps" (Default is "All") from the list on the left side to filter the search result.

Comment: The App has to be iPad compatible and iPhone/iPod incompatible.

Comment: Derfder, did you take a look at the website I linked? Based on what I've seen during the iTunes store and even the App Store on the iPad, what you are asking is not possible. Therefore, I think you have to turn to a website to help you out. It won't be exactly what you are asking for, but it **will** show iPad exclusive apps.